# How to select text using cypress

Tags: javascript, tdd, integration-testing, e2e-testing, cypress

I'm looking to test a text editor like https://github.com/brijeshb42/medium-draft using Cypress. But I can't find a way to select text using it. Does anyone have a clue on how to do that?

I'd have to select a specific text range in order for the test to be effective.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The commented answer above was the clue I needed, but it needs a couple tweaks (at least as of the version I'm using: v3.1.5).  The [link](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Arguments) has all the info, but the answer should be as follows

```
cy.type('{selectall}')
```

Note that it's ".type()" instead of ".text()" and the escape sequence is quoted...